In Groovy DSL, how to interpret an abbreviated class literal as a variable?
I am trying to build a DSL.
I want to disable Abbreviated Class literals.
Example Script:
import com.acme.Tenant; 
System.out.println(Tenant);

If I pass as a binding variable Tenant equals to MyTenantData, I expect MyTenantData as output instead of class com.acme.Tenant inferred by class literal.
I think I can achieve this with some compiler customization or transformation, but I was not able to achieve that.

In Groovy, things starting with a capital letter are assumed to be classes. You can sometimes get away with it, but often times not.  It's probably easier if you enforce all lower case variable names in the binding.  Any customization or transformation is going to be a fight against groovy's nature the whole way and I'm not 100% sure possible
